# Get value from Postman array and pass

Tags: postman

I want to get all 'branchId's and set them for parameters of next request.
Not sure how to do it.
[image]

Comment: How you want to set in the next request?

Comment: branchIds are parameters for next request

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get only the `branchId` and those make to array then apply an input of the next POST call.

This is the demo for the server

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/data/')
def print_list():
    data = {
        "profile" : {
            "contactId" :"9018398e-5c0d-43a5-99dd-0bdb8ac1b03a",
            "homeBranchId" :"07d39b5f-9f44-43ac-86c9-3bb2d6e35125"
        },
        "accountMembers" : {
            "contactId" :"485776ae-75b5-4496-9270-6af2162a955d",
            "contactDisplayName" :"bra-bra-bra",
            "contactColor" : None,
            "contactPhotoUrl" : None,
            "contactEmail" :"bra-bra-bra",
            "contactPhoneNumber" :"123-456-7890"
        },
        "branches" : [
            {
                "branchId" : "c7fd1267-a110-49f6-ab52-a36a4fe73d47",
                "branchName" :"bra-bra-bra",
                "branchPhoneNumber" :"123-456-7890",
                "branchAddress" :"bra-bra-bra",
                "branchIanaTimeZone" :"America/New_York"
            },
            {
                "branchId" : "0aa96805-a41a-4881-b0d6-0d58cc1fb68f",
                "branchName" :"bra-bra-bra",
                "branchPhoneNumber" :"123-456-7890",
                "branchAddress" :"bra-bra-bra",
                "branchIanaTimeZone" :"America/New_York"
            },
            {
                "branchId" : "4fb1aab8-b749-4893-9239-97ad880071df",
                "branchName" :"bra-bra-bra",
                "branchPhoneNumber" :"123-456-7890",
                "branchAddress" :"bra-bra-bra",
                "branchIanaTimeZone" :"America/New_York"
            }
        ]
    }
    return jsonify(data)

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def post_test():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        json = request.get_json()
        return jsonify(json), 201
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

##### Install dependency

```
pip install flask
```

##### Running server

```
python server.py
```

##### call get data API by Postman

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/data
```

##### Get Result

[image]

##### Filter and save it into an array variable

At `Tests` tab

```js
const response = pm.response.json();
// display all data
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.branches));

let onlyIds = response.branches.map(item => (item.branchId))
// display only ids after filtered
console.log(JSON.stringify(onlyIds));
pm.globals.set("onlyIds", JSON.stringify(onlyIds));
```

[image]

If call GET API again with this tests script
It will display in the console and save it into an array data.
[image]

[image]

##### Finally, It will use for the input of the array in the Body of POST call.

The result of body will display due to 'Flash` server will return the same of input body as the result of the body.

##### Access array data in input of body

```
      "branchArrayData": {{onlyIds}}
```

[image]