# Pass global variable as a required parameter of request body in postman

Tags: postman

I have saved branch Ids in Global variable.
Next I want to use that branch Ids in my next request, which is branch Id is a required parameter.
I passed global variable value in {{global variable}} double curly braces.
But response says it's 'missing required branchId parameter'

How to pass global variable value in next request body as required parameter ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this format

```
{
  "filters": {
      "branchIds": [
          "{{otherGymBr}}"
      ]
    }
}
```

This is overview of the steps

[image]

[image]

Demo code for the server by Flask

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def post_test():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        json = request.get_json()
        return jsonify(json), 201
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]

Install dependency at the terminal

```
pip install flask
```

[image]

[image]

Run server at the terminal

```
python server.py
```

[image]

[image]

You can install Post in [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/installation-and-updates/)

[image]

Click this icon after Postman launching
[image]

Add variable

```
otherGymBr
```

```
6dddbd2d-b6b8-46ae-b394-e280bdbcef0b
```

[image]

[image]

Then Press Save Icon

[image]

Add Request for POST call

[image]

Using this code in input body

```
{
  "filters": {
      "branchIds": [
          "{{otherGymBr}}",
          "12345"
      ]
    }
}
```

[image]

This Global variable in Postman

[image]

[image]

Press Send Button

It will show the value of the output body.

[image]

##### Update for handling array data

---

REST API server
Save as `server.py` file name.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/data/')
def print_list():
    data = {
        "arrayData" : [
            '6dddbd2d-b6b8-46ae-b394-e280bdbcef0b',
            '32ab08b5-3ff4-4c1e-8a7f-948d8616a32e',
            '18ec521a-04ed-4333-9c61-3fc27001c8ef',
            '552e6699-6ef5-4348-8676-0cc3c47aecec',
            '9baa3a69-a024-4fde-a1ee-db0117e5855a'
        ]
    }
    return jsonify(data)

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def post_test():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        json = request.get_json()
        return jsonify(json), 201
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#### Running it

```
python server.py
```

Get Array data and save it into `arrayData` global variable by `JSON.stringify()`
It will store the `string of array`.

```
const response = pm.response.json();
pm.globals.set("arrayData", JSON.stringify(response.arrayData));
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.arrayData));
```

[image]

[image]

##### access array data

```
"branchArrayData": {{arrayData}}
```

Result by POST call

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. It works with single branch id.
Would like to know if I have array of branch Ids in global variable.

Comment: Thanks for your acceptance, can you add a score vote me too?

Comment: Still another question 
Would like to know if I have array of branch Ids in global variable, how should I pass it in same request ?

Comment: I updated my answer to add array data handling.

Comment: I tried passing it in this way, but still it's not working.
{
  "filters": {
    "branchIds": "[{{otherGymBr}}]",
}
}

Comment: @Testtest, I updated my answer step by step. Can you try it and let me know, which step you are stuck?

Comment: My global variables store like this in Globals
["d3af60c7-1a08-4301-83c1-007b4aa8d0fb","9fb73564-c5a5-465d-a538-0df9430cc532","c47dd93f-f1bf-48de-92c8-125708bad81a","1a69fbfe-3b7e-4d5f-b76d-159f7552bb51","20babf33-2c29-4be1-af09-20ca4c4a9d30"]

I request it like below
{
  "filters": {
    "branchIds": [
        "{{otherGymBr}}"
    ],
}}

I am getting response saying '400 bad request'
Here I can't attach screen shots. Really thank you for try to help me.

Comment: @Testtest, step by test not yet going array stuff. Can you follow my 7 steps first? You needs to understand and reproduce my step first. can you try it?

Comment: Good to hear good job!

Comment: @Testtest, did you address array issue in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759686/get-value-from-postman-array-and-pass/76776284#76776284) too?

Comment: yes, it's simple change, since my variables stay on array in global variables I have to pass variable name without brackets.

Comment: Good, can you accept and vote me too in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759686/get-value-from-postman-array-and-pass/76776284#76776284)?